# Форма обратной связи в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, есть форма обратной связи, которая отображается при размере экрана больше 480px. На мобильных устройствах (размер экранов  которых меньше чем 480px) вместо этой формы появляется кнопка при нажатии на которую должна появляться эта же форма для заказа. Подскажете как реализовать? Использую бутстрап и jQuery

Comment: Дух сообщества поднял вопрос на оценку. Несмотря на общую невнятность вопроса отвечающий постарался дать ответ (поэтому в ответ плюс), а спрашивающему минус -- в том числе и за смену вопроса на лету "а теперь мне надо сделать вот так".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В bootstrap нет классов, которые могут изменять контент при разрешении именно в 480px. Поэтому нужно сделать их самому. Сделайте 2 блока, один с кнопкой, другой с формой связи и показывайте их в зависимости от разрешения экрана:

```css
.x-small-show{
  display:none;
}

@media (max-width:480px){
  .x-small-show{
      display:block;
  }
  .x-small-hide{
      display:none;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class='x-small-hide'>Форма связи</div>
<div class='x-small-show'>Кнопка вызова формы связи</div>
```

Comment: Я наверное неправильно вопрос поставил, со скрытием формы и отображением кнопки при разных размерах экрана у меня проблем не возникло, тоесть когда размер экрана меньше, чем 480 px, форма скрывается и появляется кнопка, но теперь мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку появлялось модальное окно с формой

Comment: Да, видимо, не так поставили вопрос. Лучше задать новый поэтому. Хотя я бы предложил это: http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/ — возможно, Вас устроит

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться